# Django model form not saving all fields to db

Tags: python, django

Django 1.11

Python 3.6

Allauth (without the social part for now)

Sqlite3 db backend

I am working my way through building a Django site.  Allauth is handeling the basic registration/login stuff.  I have a user profile that has a foreign key relationship into the user table -- it is not an extended user model per se.  It is a model that links to the user table.

I have a view and a form that display the profile form.  I have html5 form validation plus some form validation set up that seems to work.  If I enter bad form data and submit then the various field errors are reported.

If I enter all the required data and hit submit a record is created in the db but not all form fields with required values are inserted into the db table.  I will get first & last names, phone and birthdate. The address info never makes it to the db.  I do not see any errors reported.

Sorry for the length of the supporting material...

The **model**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            ("last_name", "first_name", "middle_name", "birthdate"),
        ]
        get_latest_by = "dateCreated"
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'birthdate']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name']),
            models.Index(fields=['last_name'], name='last_name_idx'),
            models.Index(fields=['first_name'], name='first_name_idx'),
            models.Index(fields=['birthdate']),
        ]

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    middle_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    birthdate = models.DateField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    Address1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=38,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    Address2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=38,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    City = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    State = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    Zip5 = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    Zip4 = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    dateReviewed = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        name = self.last_name + ", " + self.first_name

        if len(self.middle_name) > 0:
            name += " " + self.middle_name

        return name
```

The **Form**

```
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django import forms

from Members.models import Profile


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','middle_name','birthdate','address1','address2','city',state','zip5','zip4','phone',]

    US_STATES = [
        ("AK", "AK"),
        ...
        ("WY", "WY"),
    ]

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        label='First Name',
        required=True
    )

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        label='Last Name',
        required=True
    )

    middle_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        label='Middle',
        required=False,
        widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'optional'}))
    )

    birthdate = forms.DateField(
        label='Birthdate',
        required=True,
        widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'mm/dd/yyyy'}))
    )

    address1 = forms.CharField(
        max_length=38,
        label='Address1',
        required=True
    )

    address2 = forms.CharField(
        max_length=38,
        label='Address2',
        required=False,
        widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'optional'}))
    )

    city = forms.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        label='City',
        required=True
    )

    state = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='State',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=US_STATES
    )

    zip5 = forms.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        label='Zip5',
        required=True
    )

    zip4 = forms.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        label='Zip4',
        required=False,
        widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'optional'}))
    )

    phone = forms.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        label='Phone',
        required=True,
        widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'tel'}))
    )

    def signup(self, request, user):
        forms.Form.field_order = [
            'last_name','middle_name','birthdate','address1','address2','city','state','zip5','zip4','phone',]

        profile = user.Profile
        profile.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        profile.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        profile.middle_name = self.cleaned_data['middle_name']
        profile.birthdate = self.cleaned_data['birthdate']
        profile.Address1 = self.cleaned_data['address1']
        profile.Address2 = self.cleaned_data['address2']
        profile.City = self.cleaned_data['city']
        profile.State = self.cleaned_data['state']
        profile.Zip5 = self.cleaned_data['zip5']
        profile.Zip4 = self.cleaned_data['zip4']
        profile.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        profile.save()

    def clean_birthdate(self):
        birthdate = self.cleaned_data['birthdate']

        eighteen_years_ago = datetime.date.today() - relativedelta(years=18)

        if birthdate > eighteen_years_ago:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Must be 18 or older', code='invalid')

        return birthdate
```

The **view**

```
from django.core.exceptions import *
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import Log
from .models import Profile


def add_new_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            my_render = render(request, 'Members/index.html')
        else:
            my_render = render(request, 'Members/index.html', {'profileForm': form})
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
        my_render = render(request, 'Members/index.html', {'profileForm': form})

    return my_render


def index(request):
    Log.add("at top of Members.views")

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/accounts/login')

    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        my_render = render(request, 'Members/index.html')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        my_render = add_new_profile(request)

    return my_render
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your models.py

```
address1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=38,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    address2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=38,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    city = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    zip5 = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    zip4 = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
```

I think it should be lowercase. forms.py has all lowercase like address1, address2, city, state, zip5 and zip4.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought the assignments in the `signup` method were taking care of the text case differences.  Obviously not.

Comment: I am glad that helped you. :)